# Cropping an image and putting it in a picture box

Tags: c#, crop

im trying to crop an image from a sprite sheet and put it in a picturebox but its not working, any ideas are welcome

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image Result = Crop(@"C:\Users\William\Documents\Sprites\Player\Male\Default\Light.png", 40, 60, 367, 701);
        pictureBox1.Image = Result;
    }

    public Image Crop(string img, int width, int height, int x, int y)
    {
        try
        {
            Image image = Image.FromFile(img);
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            bmp.SetResolution(80, 60);

            Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            gfx.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            gfx.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), x, y, width, height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            // Dispose to free up resources
            image.Dispose();
            bmp.Dispose();
            gfx.Dispose();

            return bmp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

i dont think its the crop function thats wrong but im not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather pointless

```
bmp.Dispose();
return bmp;
```

You're returning a bitmap that can't be used for anything, because it is already disposed.